# Chrome Dev Tools responsive mode is broken

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I haven't had this problem before, but in the last few days, anytime I enter Chrome Dev Tools responsive mode, only the top left 1/4 of the screen is visible. the other 3/4s of the screen are white.

To be clear, its not scaling the content to fit inside the top left 1/4, it shows the frame correctly but cuts off all but the top left 1/4 of the screen.

I'm running chrome 65 on macOS. I uninstalled plugins, tried incognito, and even completely uninstalled, restart and reinstall. Bug persists.

I've validated that its not just the site I'm on my checking the site on another mac running the same version of macOS and Chrome with no bug.

Update: This problem is gone in chrome canary, however using that browser 100% is not feasible.

Comment: Same problem happening to me as well since the last update

Comment: I had the same problem but it's fixed now if you update Chrome

Comment: Similar issue with Chrome v65.0.3325.162 on Windows PC. Responsive mode rarely renders the proper full width of viewport. Moz working fine in responsive mode. Chrome fine if you resize window with dev tools open (or not) -- only happens in "emulation" mode. Above a certain size (laptop + up) all is fine -- but when Chrome thinks you want to emulate another device (not just viewport size test) the issue occurs.